# Swift how to close Facebook graph block

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, block

I want, and I don't know how to =(, close my Facebook graph block

My problem is that I want to save the username of my user facebook in a variable to use it later (another view controller), but I can't because my block is closed after I try to save the data.

This is my delegate function :

```
    // Facebook Delegate Methods
    func loginButton(connection: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("Error")
        }
        else {
            println("User logged in")
            self.returnUserData()
        }
    }
```

And this is my function which use facebook graph api

```
// Here my block that I want to close, maybe with completion closure inside
    func returnUserData()
    {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"])
        // Launch asynchronous function
        var userName : String = "error"
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                println(result)
                userName = result["first_name"] as! String
            }
        })
    }
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Can you add what error or what problem you're having?

Comment: Done ;) @thefredelement

Comment: Just declare your username variable outside of the closure so you can access it elsewhere.

Comment: No I've already tried. I just can valorise my variable into my block and when I try to print it outside of my block, the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example, you can set the variable outside of the scope of your closure then ask it to perform a specific func when it's value is set like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myString : String = "123" {

    didSet {

        self.stringUpdated()
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myString = "456" // this would take place in your graph request closure
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func stringUpdated() {

    println("got it, string is \(myString)")
}


}
```